# unbiased estimator and efficiency

Tags: unbiased-estimator, efficiency

can someone plese  clarify a doubt for me?
Let (X1, . . . , Xn) be a random sample of i.i.d. random variables with expected value $µ$ and variance $σ^2$

Consider the following estimator of $µ$:
$T_{n}(a)=aX_n+(1−a)\bar{X}_{n−1}$
where $Xn$ is the n − th observed random variable and  $\bar{X}_{n−1}$ is the sample
mean based on n − 1 observations

1. Find value of a such that $T_{n}(a)$ is an unbiased estimator for µ
2. Find value of $a*$ such that $Tn(a*)$ is the most efficient estimator for $µ$
   within the class $Tn(a)$?
   what I have done is this:

E(Tn)= a$µ$+(1-a) $µ$= a$µ$+$µ$-a$µ$= $µ$ since this quantity does not depend on a this estimator is unbiased for each value of a

2. to find a value of $a*$ such that $T_{n}(a*)$ is the most efficient for $µ$ the variance of $T_{n}(a*)$ should be less than $T_{n}(a)$
   so my attempt is Var$(T_{n}(a*))$<Var$(T_{n}(a))$

$a*^2$ $σ^2$+$σ^2$-2$a*$$σ^2$ $<$ $a^2$ $σ^2$+$σ^2$-2$a$$σ^2$
grouping both sides $σ^2$ and simplifying for this quantity I end up with

$2a*(a*-1)$ < $2a(a-1)$

is my attempt correct to find the value of $a*$ ?

Comment: So you have partially  used LaTeX.  If your were to use `$T_{n}(a)=aX_n+1−a)\bar{X}_{n−1}$`  you would get $T_{n}(a) = a X_n+(1−a)\bar{X}_{n−1}$ which might be more readable

Comment: I edited the post I hope is more readable